# Rails: add form in index page of a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

models:

Order **has_many** Materials
Material **belongs_to** Order

**materials_contrller.rb**

```
 def index
    @order = Order.find_by_id(params[:order_id])
    @materials = @order.materials
  end

def update
    @order = Order.find_by_id(params[:order_id])
    @material = @order.materials.find_by_id(params[:id])

    if @material.update_attributes(material_params)
      redirect_to order_materials_path(@order)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end 
end
```

I want to add a form in materials index page , **index.html.erb**

```
    <% @materials.each do |material| %>
                <%= form_for material, url: {controller:"materials", action: "update"} do |f| %>
                <%= f.check_box :material_urgent %>
                <%= f.submit %>
                <% end %>
<%end%>
```

but I got an error when I tried it on page 
**http://localhost:3000/orders/1/materials**

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Materials#index
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"materials", :order_id=>"1"}
```

Anybody could help? Thanks!

Comment: `<%= form_for [@order, material]...` does that make a difference if try that?

Comment: I tried your way, still show the same error @mrvncaragay